# Write a dict of dict into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have dictinoary is like this

```
{id1:{t1:1, t2:2, t3:4, t5:3 ...}, id2:{t2:1, t3:3...},...id3332:{tX:X, tX:X}}
```

While the length of dict is 3332, so got 3332 ids here. But the length of each id may not be the same. And those keys `(t1, t2, t3...)` are also random.

I want to output those data into a csv file like this:

```
IDs   t1  t2   t3 t4  t5 ...
id1    1   2   4   0   3
id2    0   1   3   0   0  
id3    0   1   0   4   0
 :
id3332   ...
```

Which means for each id, if there is a value for a time `(e.g. for id1, t1=1, t2=2)`, then output that value in corresponding position, if no value for that time`(e.g. for id1, no value for t4, then output 0)`.

I just checked documentation and tried to use `csv.write` but didn't figure it out.

A sample data can be generated using

```
sample = {103061863: {'26/08/2014 07:20:00': '"5"', '23/08/2014 20:25:00': '"8"', '14/08/2014 18:55:00': '"6"'}, 103061862: {'06/08/2014 11:15:00': '"5"', '21/08/2014 13:10:00': '"5"', '01/08/2014 05:55:00': '"5"'}, 103061819: {'02/08/2014 09:50:00': '"6"', '17/08/2014 07:30:00': '"5"', '08/08/2014 20:30:00': '"7"', '23/08/2014 20:25:00': '"7"', '21/08/2014 09:50:00': '"6"', '17/08/2014 15:00:00': '"7"'}}
```

So want a csv file in this form:

```
IDs   '26/08/2014 07:20:00'  '23/08/2014 20:25:00'   '14/08/2014 18:55:00' t4  t5 ...
103061863    5                        8               6         ...
103061862    0                        3               0         ... 
103061819    0                        7               0         ...
```

Comment: Try to put some code in the question, so we can help you

Comment: I think your easiest option would be to transfer the dict into a pandas dataframe and then simply export it to a csv with the to_csv() function

Comment: @MarcvT Is it builtin? Do I need to download it and install it?

Comment: yes, you would need to install pandas, but that would be really easy with pip install. For the code, just look at Roman's answer. That should work perfectly

Comment: @MarcvT is there any way to sort the data frame according to the time?

Comment: If time is the index, then use pandas.df.sort_index() otherwise use the answer posted by Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good case to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library - turn your dict into [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) first and then save it [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0)
df.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: I guess I am gonna love this library!

Comment: is there any way to sort the data frame according to the time?

Comment: `df.columns = sorted(df.columns)` should do the trick